# Geofencing in Android not working

Tags: android, geofencing

I am trying to do Geofencing in Android. But Somehow it doesn't seem to be working.
Can anyone find the bug in my code.

Here is the MainActivity.

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;
    public static final int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 100;
    private List<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static final String TAG = "Activity";
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    double currentLatitude = 8.62808317, currentLongitude = 76.90051408;
    Boolean locationFound;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

            int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                initGoogleAPIClient();
                createGeofences(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Your Device doesn't support Google Play Services.");
            }

            // Create the LocationRequest object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(1 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                    .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        }

    }

    public void initGoogleAPIClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionAddListener)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionFailedListener)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks connectionAddListener =
            new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");

//                    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
//
//                    if (location == null) {
//                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, MainActivity.this);
//
//                    } else {
//                        //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
//                        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
//                        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
//
//                        Log.i(TAG, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude);
//
//                        //createGeofences(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
//                        //registerGeofences(mGeofenceList);
//                    }

                    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                            mGoogleApiClient,
                            getGeofencingRequest(),
                            getGeofencePendingIntent()
                    ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Saving Geofence");

                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Registering geofence failed: " + status.getStatusMessage() +
                                        " : " + status.getStatusCode());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");

                }
            };

    private GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener connectionFailedListener =
            new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                }
            };

    /**
     * Create a Geofence list
     */
    public void createGeofences(double latitude, double longitude) {
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Geofence fence = new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(id)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, 100)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .build();
        mGeofenceList.add(fence);
    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
        if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
        // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
    }

}
```

Here is the Service Declaration

Service Declaration in Manifest.

```
<service
        android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: What exactly is not working and what do you expect it to do that it is not doing?

Comment: I added a circular region around my current location..so when I run the app, it should show notifcation "entered" and moved 1 meter it should have shown "Exited", but this is not happening.   
setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, 1)

Comment: I don't think a GPS on many devices has precision accurate down to a meter

Comment: "Another strategy for getting best results from your geofences is to set a minimum radius of 100 meters" -- [Source](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

Comment: I changed to 100 metres, but still not working. Since it is my current location, it should have triggered "Enter" upon launch itself. that is not coming.

Comment: Hmm. Are you following the documentation from that link I just posted?

Comment: cricket_007  :- Yes I followed the same tutorial.

Comment: And there are no error messages? It just "doesn't work"?

Comment: I updated the code, still not working.

Comment: Sorry...I changed the MainActivity according to the Google Docs.

Comment: I see that the `onConnectionFailed` is empty. Can you try placing something there?

Comment: Or, you could try to see if the [Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing) sample works, then you would know if the problem is the code or your device.

Comment: Found the Issue.. The Code in the Github was similar to mine, but there the circular region was 1.6Kms. I tried changing from 100 to 200m, then it worked, seems like the minimum may be 200.

Comment: Yeah, changing the radius was mentioned in the "best practices" section of that page. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Anyway ..thanks for your time...